# unknown attribute error: 'availabilities_attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Beginner to ruby on rails and I completely stuck on this problem I have in my nested form.

What I am trying to accomplish: I want to setup a form where the user can set the closing and opening time for the days in the week. I have a child model: Availability and a parent model: Parking, and each parking will have 6 rows in availability for each day of the week, 0-6.

The error I get when I submit:

```
Started PATCH "/parkings/12/availabilities" for ::1 at 2020-10-07 14:24:44 -0700
Processing by AvailabilitiesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MmyvqkUkM+YSPO4PZRB/baB8BmXaCFsPFoMm/RC7mAmPnxT9tBXnF4dL5dbMahCAldakWqMyvWaiDMutFTjxjw==", "parking"=>{"availabilities_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"open_time"=>"", "closing_time"=>"", "id"=>"55"}, "1"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"56"}, "2"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"57"}, "3"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"58"}, "4"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"59"}, "5"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"60"}, "6"=>{"open_time"=>"9", "closing_time"=>"8", "id"=>"61"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"12"}
  Parking Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "parkings".* FROM "parkings" WHERE "parkings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Availability Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "availabilities".* FROM "availabilities" WHERE "availabilities"."parking_id" = ?  [["parking_id", 12]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


  
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'availabilities_attributes' for Availability.):
  
app/controllers/availabilities_controller.rb:31:in `update'
  Rendering /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendering /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendering /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zein/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (127.7ms)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2020-10-07 14:24:45 -0700
MessagesChannel stopped streaming from conversation_
NotificationsChannel stopped streaming from notification_1
```

Avalability.rb:

```
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parking

  def day
    Date::DAYNAMES[read_attribute(:day)]
  end

end
```

create_availabilities.rb

```
class CreateAvailabilities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :availabilities do |t|
      t.references :parking, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :day
      t.time :open_time
      t.time :closing_time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Parking.rb

```
class Parking < ApplicationRecord
  enum instant: {Request: 0, Instant: 1}

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :availabilities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :availabilities
```

The 6 records in the availability is automatically created in the parking_controller when a User creates a parking spot.

Parkings_controller.rb

```
class ParkingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_parking, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:listing, :pricing, :description, :photo_upload, :amenities, :location, :update]

  def index
    @parkings = current_user.parkings
  end

  def new
    @parking = current_user.parkings.build
  end

  def create
    # if !current_user.is_active_host
    #   return redirect_to payout_method_path, alert: "Please Connect to Stripe Express first."
    # end

    @parking = current_user.parkings.build(parking_params)

    if @parking.save
      redirect_to listing_parking_path(@parking), notice: "Saved!"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
      render :new
    end

     # the availability record is created here:
    (0..6).each do |i|
     @availabilities = @parking.availabilities.create(day: i)
    end
  end
```

availabilities_controller.rb

```
class AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_parking
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:index, :update]

  def index

  end

  def new

  end

  # def create
  #   @parking = Parking.find(params[:id])
  #   # @availabilities = @parking.availabilities.new
  #   @availabilities = @parking.availabilities.build(availabilities_params)
  #   @availabilities.day = 0
  #
  #    if @availabilities.save
  #      redirect_to listing_parking_path(@parking), notice: "Saved!"
  #    else
  #      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
  #      render :new
  #    end
  # end

  def update
    @availabilities = Availability.where(:parking_id => @parking.id)

   if @availabilities.update(availabilities_params)
      redirect_to listing_parking_path(@parking), notice: "Saved!"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

      def availabilities_params
        params.require(:parking).permit(availabilities_attributes: [:id, :open_time, :closing_time])
      end

      def set_parking
        @parking = Parking.find(params[:id])
      end

      def is_authorised
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @parking.user_id
      end

end
```

views/availabilities/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card border shadow">

        <div class="card-header bg-white h3">
          Availability
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <%= form_for @parking, :url => availabilities_parking_path(@parking)  do |f| %>
              <%= f.fields_for :availabilities do |p| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Opening Time</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                           <%= p.text_field :open_time, readonly: false, placeholder: "9:00 AM", class: "form-control datetimepicker-input"%>
                   </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Closing Time</label>
                          <%= p.text_field :closing_time, readonly: false, placeholder: "8:00 PM", class: "form-control datetimepicker-input"%>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <% end %>


                <br/><br/>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button button-large curb-color" %>
                </div>

            <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#opening_time').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            useCurrent: false

        });

        $('#closing_time').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            useCurrent: false
        });

    });
</script>
```

routes.rb (the parking section)

```
  resources :parkings, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      get 'listing'
      get 'pricing'
      get 'description'
      get 'photo_upload'
      get 'amenities'
      get 'location'
      get 'preload'
      get 'preview'
      get 'availabilities' => 'availabilities#new'
      post 'availabilities' => 'availabilities#create'
      patch 'availabilities' => 'availabilities#update'
    end
    resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :reservations, only: [:create]
    resources :calendars

  end
```

I approached this implementation after researching a lot online but I am open to any suggestion that will get me to the end result and fix this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your form appears set up fine to treat availability as nested attributes of `Parking`. So your `availabilities_attributes` in `params` is a hash of attribute hashes (keyed by Availability ID). But then in the controller (`#update`) you don't update the `Parking` instance, and instead just treat `availabilities_attributes` as though it was a simple hash of attributes for a single `Availability`, which it isn't. I'd have a rethink of your controllers, but at a minimum changing `#update` to update `@parking.update(availabilities_attributes)` should get you moving.

Comment: Yep that got it work! Thank you. `@parking.update(availabilities_params)`. Could you explain a little more on why @parking.update works here? Is it updating all the records that have the parking_id associated with`@parking`? @rmlockerd

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` methods like `#create`, `#update`, etc. take a Hash of model attributes. When you specify that a model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` another model (where there is a `has_one` or `has_many` relationship), Rails will also allow you to pass attributes for one or more instances of the nested models under the key '*pluralized_model*_attributes'. For `has_one` the value is just a hash of the nested object's attributes. For a `has_many` relationship, the value is an array of hashes, one for each nested instance being added/updated (or deleted if you allow for that). So, in your case it would look something like:

```ruby
attr_hash = {
  parking_attr1: value, parking_attr2: value,
  availabilities_attributes: [ 
    {id: 1, attr1: value, ...},
    {id: 2, attr1: value, ...},
    ...
  }
}
@parking.update(attr_hash)
```

When you define your view/form, part of the magic Rails provides is to ensure that the fields are named such that the `params` hash ends up more or less directly useful with `#create`, `#update`, etc. In your case you define a `form_for` a specific `Parking` instance, and then define `fields_for` `Availability` instances. Rails interprets that to mean your controller will be updating a `Parking` instance with nested attributes, and structures the fields names (and resulting `params` hash accordingly). Your original code didn't work because your controller switched gears and tried to update a single `Availability` when everything was set up to update a `Parking` instance with nested `Availabilities`.

Note that just because you've declared that `Parking` can accept nested attributes doesn't mean you can't deal with an `Availability` instance separately. You could, for example, create a view so that the `form_for` is for a particular `Availability` instance and then update that instance in your controller. You just need to make sure that the paradigm (nested or non-nested) you use in your view matches what your controller expects.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you for taking the time to help me out! Much appreciated.